# Fourier Transform for a Convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, convolution, mathematica

Alright, so I am using the Convolution property of Fourier Transforms to find a function $f(x)$.  So the obvious equation: $h(x) = f(x) \ast g(x)$.

Definitions:

$$g(x)=Rect\left[\frac x w \right]$$

```
h(x) =  al*exp(-((abs((x-b1)./c1).^d)))+a2
a2 =  1.205e+004  ;
al =  1.778e+005  ;
b1 =       94.88  ;
c1 =       224.3  ;
d =       4.077  ;
```

That is,
$$h(x)=a_1 \exp\left[-\left(\frac{|x-b_1|}{c_1}\right)^d \right]+a_2$$
with the constants defined above.

So I want to find $f(x)$ by fourier transforming everything.  The only prblem is that I can not find the fourier transform of h(x).  I have tried to use `fft()` in matlab, `FourierTransform[h,x,$\omega$]` in mathematica.  In matlab, when I apply fft to both $h(x)$  and the `Rect[]` function, I do not end up with a reasonable result after `ifft` (most likely due to the zeros of sinc).  However, in Mathematica, I can not even get a result for the FT of $h(x)$.  The computer just sits and does nothing.  So I am really stuck.  I do not have enough math background to try and find the FT by hand.  So if anyone has any advice (or a really fast computer that will actually perform the FT).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The description of Mathematica command [FourierTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierTransform.html) says

> gives the symbolic Fourier transform

It rather unlikely that the Fourier transform of your  $h$ has a sensible symbolic expression,  due to fractional power $d$. But you can transform $h$ numerically, as explained in [Numerical Fourier transform of a complicated function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1714).

Also, I am not surprised that you don't like the result of $\mathcal F^{-1}(\mathcal F h/\mathcal F g)$. [Deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) is not a straightforward operation.